# My RewriteRule is matching everything

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out why this rule matches everything, and how to make in only match author.php?user_name=user_name

```
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  author.php?user_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

I works for the author pages (example: /author/joe), but if I go to the about page, for example, I get 
/author/about.

As requested I am adding the complete contents of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  author.php?user_name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please post your other rules too. This rule cannot be causing the problem (since it doesn't rewrite anything *to* `/author/`, it rewrites *from* that). Also what is the URL for your about page? Perhaps you have a rule rewriting just `/authorname`? Please post them all as they appear in your setup.

Comment: @user2493235 I've edited my question to include all the rules.

Comment: Thanks Rob. And what's the URL for your about page?

Comment: @user2493235 it's the domain.com/about.php. I tried adding the forward slash and that seems to have fixed it as per bobo, though I am not entirely clear why.

Comment: Well if you added a forward slash in your link, and the link is on a page within /author, then that is meaning that you will be taken to example.com/about. Without the forward slash in the link you are asking for example.com/author/about because the forward slash says "start from root" and not having the forward slash means "start in the current directory". There's nothing wrong with your redirects it's just gaining a better understanding of relative and absolute links, which you could Google for. You don't have an author/ directory, but URLs behave that way when they have forward slashes in.

Comment: P.S. It would be cool to accept and upvote bobo's answer :)

Comment: @user2493235 thank you for helping figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps in your HTML you should link to `/about`, starting with a slash, so the URL wouldn't be created relative to the current page, but to the root of the website?

Btw, you can express your rule in a slightly shorter manner:

```
RewriteRule ^author/([\w-]+)/?$  author.php?user_name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Good idea, it's a possibility if he's clicking a link on a page in `/author/`.